# "The remote server returned an error (502) Bad Gateway" while downloading image file from url

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to download image from website, but it gives me error i.e. (The remote server returned an error: (502) Bad Gateway). I search a lot on internet but didn't get exact solution. This code is working on some website but on few website it is showing above error.
Please check my below code...

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim filename As String = Application.StartupPath
    If Not filename.EndsWith("\") Then filename &= "\"
    txtLocalFile.Text = "D:\a.jpg" 'filename & " "
    txtRemoteFile.Text = "http://bseworld.bseindia.com/eventgallery/cricket2015/19Feb2015/2.jpg"
End Sub


Private Sub btnDownload_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDownload.Click
    Application.DoEvents()
    Try
        Dim web_client As WebClient = New WebClient

        Dim wp = New WebProxy("proxy ip", proxy_port)
        wp.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("uname", "password", "domainname")
        web_client.Proxy = wp
        web_client.DownloadFile(txtRemoteFile.Text, txtLocalFile.Text)

        MessageBox.Show("Done")
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

    End Sub
```

Can you please tell me which part of code is missing or i have to change..

Comment: It's an error on the server.  If you own the code on the server, look there.  If you don't, contact the support team and ask their help.

Comment: @tim.. what kind of issue you think in the code on the server....

Comment: I have no idea, but something went wrong at the server.  That's why I suggested you either look at the code (and logs) on the server, if you own it, or contact the folks that do.

Comment: Try to set a UserAgent. For example `web_client.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)";`. Some sites need this for security reason.

Comment: @ClaudioP: i tried... but no luck...

Comment: Here's a suggestion: see if you can replicate the error manually in your browser.  What did you do to get to the error? How do you solve it manually? Then see if you can replicate the solution in your code.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Comment: @JohnSaunders: Ok...i'll keep this in mind....

Answer (score 0):

I did some RND and finally my code is working.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim filename As String = Application.StartupPath
    If Not filename.EndsWith("\") Then filename &= "\"
    txtLocalFile.Text = "" 'filename & " "
    txtRemoteFile.Text = ""
End Sub

Private Sub btnDownload_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDownload.Click
    Application.DoEvents()
    Dim web_client As WebClient = New WebClient
    Try
        web_client.UseDefaultCredentials = True
        web_client.DownloadFile(txtRemoteFile.Text, txtLocalFile.Text)
        MessageBox.Show("Done")

    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim wp = New WebProxy("Proxy IP", Proxy_port)
        wp.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("MachineUsername", "Machine Password", "Domain Name")
        web_client.Proxy = wp
        web_client.DownloadFile(txtRemoteFile.Text, txtLocalFile.Text)
        MessageBox.Show("Done")
    End Try

End Sub
```